# how to pass parameter to execute in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm new to chef. Recently, I'm studying the resources, I got a problem on how to pass parameter to command in execute in chef. Here's the details --
I searched this page -- https://discourse.chef.io/t/pass-parameter-to-bash-script-and-call-bash-scripts-in-chef-cookbook/10431  -- it looks using ruby variable format #{xxx} can pass a variable in recipe to the script in "execute" in recipe
I made a test, first my recipe --

```
execf="haha"

file '/tmp/e.sh' do
    content '
#!/bin/bash
cat /tmp/e.log
DT=`date +%F" "%T`
echo $1" "${DT} >> /tmp/e.log
'
    mode '755'
    execf="e1"
    notifies :run, 'execute[e.sh]', :delayed
end

file '/tmp/e2.sh' do
    content '
#!/bin/bash
cat /tmp/e.log
DT=`date +%F" "%T`
echo $1" "${DT} >> /tmp/e.log
'
    mode '777'
    execf="e2"
    notifies :run, 'execute[e.sh]', :delayed
end

execute 'e.sh' do
    command '/tmp/e.sh #{execf}'
    action :nothing
end
```

I think -- this can record resouce "e.sh" or "e2.sh"'s runtime to e.log. And there's no syntax error when run "chef-client". But to my suprise -- the #{execf} -- is always a "" string while calling /tmp/e.sh... So in e.log, I can only see --

```
 2022-05-13 22:04:48
 2022-05-13 22:17:44
 2022-05-13 22:19:07
```

Only a "" was passing to the /tmp/e.sh as $1... At first I think maybe it's due to the execf is a local variable in ruby so I tried @execf and $execf ... but all didn't work. Maybe in recipe, I shouldn't use variable, but should use node attribute? But I can't find how to modify node attribute in resource...
Please kind help. Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the use of single quotes (`''`) in the `command`. Single quotes in Ruby don't allow for interpolation of the variable `#{execf}`. You should rewrite it as:

```rb
execute 'e.sh' do
  command "/tmp/e.sh #{execf}"
  action :nothing
end
```

*However variable assignment (such as `execf="e1"`) in the `file` resources will not have any effect.* You will get something like `haha 2022-05-13 22:04:48` in the logs.

**Edit**

> However variable assignment (such as `execf="e1"`) in the `file` resources will not have any effect.

Turns out that the variable assignment from within resource is also compiled, and last assigned value is used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know how to change that variable in resource block ? That is important for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Variables or node attributes will need to be defined outside the resources. In what circumstances would a change in the variable needed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But with my test-- I found the variable execf has been changed in resource-- and it's not resource relative -- so when only "e.sh" triggered, the execf finally still was assigned value of "e2"... So it looks no matter resource fired or not , the variable action inside will be processed. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it and does update the variable from within the resource also. Its the same as defining the variable outside the resource.

Comment: Yes. That "execf" 's value depends on the location of resource -- execute 'e.sh' -- if it's before resource -- file 'e.sh' -- then once fired, it always is "haha"; if it's between resources -- file 'e.sh' and file 'e2.sh' -- then once fired, it always is "e1". And if at the end of recipe,  it always is "e2". Thanks again for your lesson.